# VI JAVA: Getting Custom Fields (Names and Values) from Virtual Machines

Tags: java, api, sdk, vmware, vsphere

The Custom Fields of my Virtual Machines (Name and Value). Those fields that are located under "annotations" on the Summary tab. Nope, I don't need the annotation property itself, I really do need the Custom Fields.

I've managed to the the values themselves from the custom fields by doing `vm.getSummary.getCustomValue`, then casting it to `CustomFieldStringValue` and doing `.getValue` for each Custom Field of the array.

Here's an example, (`vmObject` is the object I created for the fields that I need to grab):

```
CustomFieldValue[] customFieldValue = vm.getSummary().getCustomValue();       
CustomFieldStringValue BU = (CustomFieldStringValue) customFieldValue[0];
vmObject.setBusinessUnit(BU.getValue());
```

I know there's CustomFieldsManager and CustomFieldDef, they both have the "name" property that I need, what I don't know is how do I map to these from where's I'm currently at...

Edit/Progress:
So I've managed to grab `CustomFieldsManager` and `CustomFieldsDef`, by doing:

```
ManagedObjectReference customFieldOR = si.getServiceContent().getCustomFieldsManager();
        CustomFieldsManager CFManager = new CustomFieldsManager(vm.getServerConnection(), customFieldOR);
        CustomFieldDef[] CFDef = CFManager.getField();
```

The bad thing about this is that I would need to iterate through the `CustomFieldDef` array for every VM and Custom Field in the VM... *cringe*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like iterating is the way to go. I guess the upside is that a vsphere call is not done on each iteration, since I managed to grab all custom fields on one or two calls:

```
ManagedObjectReference customFieldOR = si.getServiceContent().getCustomFieldsManager();
        CustomFieldsManager CFManager = new CustomFieldsManager(vm.getServerConnection(), customFieldOR);
        CustomFieldDef[] CFDef = CFManager.getField();
```

There, I have an array of all custom fields.

Then, when iterating through VMs, I grabbed their `CustomFieldValue` property, which has the Key. From there on, its mapping Keys using the `CustomFieldDef` and `CustomFieldValue` Arrays. Keeping in mind that CustomFieldStringValue is the property that has the actual Value of the Custom Field - so casting from `CustomFieldValue` to `CustomFieldStringValue` is needed.

Suggested improvements are always welcome! Hope this helps folks in the future.